# Replacement for HttpResponse.ContentEncoding ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, content-encoding

Does anyone know if there is a replacement in ASP.NET 5 for HttpResponse.ContentEncoding? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example:

```
var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
mediaType.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
httpContext.Response.ContentType = mediaType.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders.EncoderExtensions

have HtmlEncode, JavaScriptStringEncode and UrlEncode extensions

and the base Class is Microsoft.Framework.WebEncoders